# Problem with apache virtualhost

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host

I'm setting up a local apache server. I use the xampp 1.7 package on windows. One site requires to be in the root directory, so i set up a virtual host to make it apear from root.

In the host file, i've added an entry (127.0.0.1 app.localhost).

I've added the virtual host to the apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost app.localhost:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Tools/xampp1.7/htdocs/ovs-v2"
    ServerName app.localhost

    <Directory "D:/Tools/xampp1.7/htdocs/ovs-v2/">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The virtual host itself does work, when i go to app.localhost, i get the correct website. When I go to localhost, i get the normal webroot. But when I go to 127.0.0.1, i get the app.localhost website.

If i disable this virtual host, then all works normal. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling Apache that when it receives a request for a specific named host (VirtualHost app.localhost), it should respond with a specific configuration. Read more about name-based virtual hosts here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: Classic case of RTM before use. Thx.